# trouble converting 5 line snippet javascript to query, who knows a solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, converters

Im having issues getting below code to convert to query and work:

The original javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
        var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
        return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
    }
    function stream() {
        var active = document.getElementById("start").value == "stop";
        getFlashMovie("v1stream").setProperty("src", !active ? document.getElementById('url2').value : null);
</script>
```

Converted and modified jquery version:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  alert ('before');
  swfobject.getObjectById("v1stream").setProperty("src", "rtmp://localhost/mystream");
  alert ('after');

});
```

- first snippet works 2nd not
- getting an error swfobject.getObjectById("v1stream") is null
- It never throws the 2nd alert 'after' so it crashes on getting the swfobject...
- tried all kinds of things for about an hour now, anyone knows how to fix this? thx

**UPDATE:**

This is the html used

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553534700"
        id="v1stream" width="562" height="547"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
  <param name="movie" value="/assets/im.swf"/>
  <param name="quality" value="high"/>
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"/>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
  <embed src="/assets/v1stream.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000"
         play="true" loop="false" quality="high"
         allowFullScreen="true"
         allowScriptAccess="always"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
  </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for SWFObject: http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/ (and) http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Comment: The two bits of code are doing completely different things. The only thing jQuery is bing used for in the second example is a substitute for `window.onload`.

Comment: the setProperty function is a call to the SWF it includes this function to pass data into the SWF on load

Comment: Why would you take perfectly good working javascript and turn it into jQuery?  jQuery should be used only when needed or when it's faster to write.  jQuery is just javascript using a library so it isn't inherently better in any way and is often slower performance, though often faster to write.

Comment: I want the code to be executed automatically and jquery because everything else is jquery and its more nice to have all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery version should be:

```
//wait for document.ready to fire
$(document).ready(function() {

    //select an element by ID and then change it's `src` attribute
    $('#v1stream').attr('src', "rtmp://localhost/mystream");
});
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work for you as I'm not sure what the `swfobject` script does when you call `.setProperty()`, but if you just want to change an attribute on an element, you can do so with the code above.

Docs:

- `document.ready`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: the setProperty function is a call to the SWF it includes this function to pass data into the SWF on load. The html to include the SWF also contains a src property but this is the property to the SWF file itself, not passing in the rtmpd stream location